# AutoHotKey issue: My simple window resize hotkey isn't working

Tags: autohotkey

I created a new keyboard shortcut to resize and move the active (top-most) window. Any ideas why isn't it working?

```
^+o::
WinGet, active_id, ID, A
WinMove, ahk_id %active_id%, 0, 0, 1024, 768
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a missing comma in my call to WinMove. *Duh.*

```
WinGetTitle, WindowTitle, A
WinMove, %WindowTitle%,, 0, 0, 768, 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just

```
WinMove,A,, 0, 0, 768, 1024
```

dont need no WinGetTitle, it will move the "**A**"ctive window (no cap fr)

also, i think WinMove doesn't resize exactly to 1024x768, Width is -14 pixels off and Height is -7 pixels off, its a little smaller, unnoticeable but...